# jQuery each with timeout

Tags: jquery, get, settimeout, each

I have the following function which runs OK except for one thing. There is no consequence in what it appends first.

```
(function biograf(){
  var placeholder = $('#top-imageholder');
  $('ul#biomenu > li').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var pageLink = obj.find('a:first').attr('href');
    $.get(pageLink, function(data) {
      placeholder.append( $(data).find('#top-imageholder').html() );
      placeholder.append( $(data).find('#top-imageholder').siblings('ul') );
    });
  });
})();
```

I would like the function to append the placeholder in the order my list items are placed in the #biomenu.

It does this 90% of the time, but once in a while it appends in different orders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use `setTimeout` anywhere?

Comment: You might want to retitle this question. There's no timeout, rather an asynchronous `.get()`. The order is being defeated by the asynchronicity.

Comment: You should consider bundling all your pagelinks into a single request and have the server compose the entire response. This will fix the problem and avoid bombing the server with many near-simultaneous requests.

Comment: I know there is no timeout in the code, and it might be confusing i wrote it, but what I meant by it was that one might be able to do a timeout in the function to adress the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well got it to work with the following code:

```
(function biograf(){
  var placeholder = $('#top-imageholder');
  var item = $('ul#biomenu > li');
  var index = 0;

  (function loop(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var pageLink = item.eq(index).find('a:first').attr('href');
      if( pageLink != undefined ){
        $.get(pageLink, function(data) {
          placeholder.append( $(data).find('#top-imageholder').html() );
          placeholder.append( $(data).find('#top-imageholder').siblings('ul') );
        });     
        index++;
        loop();
      }
    });
  })();
})();
```

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way, or if the code could be tweeked. But it works! :)

Thanks for all the replies though!

Comment: +1 cause it was the solution which worked for you. Off course this could mess up again if any of the calls takes a little longer to get back. worst-case, you could always change$.get to a $.ajax with async option = false (last resort off course as async = false stalls the UI with each call)

Comment: wouldn't $.ajax option async=false be the same as $.get, or how do you mean it's different?

Comment: `$.get` executes asynchronous. As `$.get` is simply shorthand for `$.ajax({url: url, data: data, success: success, dataType: dataType});` using `$.ajax` would allow you to specify the `async: false` option which will execute the request `synchronous` instead of `asynchronous` meaning it will wait for the request to come back before continuing to execute. Though this can fix issues similar to yours it is **not** the preferred way of dealing with it as `synchronous` execution will lock the UI until the request is done, potentially freezing the UI if the request hangs on the server.

Comment: More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, check the notes on the `async` option. Again, not a good solution, just **an** alternative if you realy stuck.

Comment: Neither `setTimeout()` nor `async:false` is a good solution. The first is not guaranteed to work, and the second is not fully cross-browser. See my suggestion in the comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Order results with `$.when` (untested code):

```
(function (){

  var placeholder = $('#top-imageholder');
  var promises = [];

  $('ul#biomenu > li').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var pageLink = obj.find('a:first').attr('href');
    promises.push($.get(pageLink));
  });

  $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
    $.each(arguments, function(data) {
      placeholder.append( $(data).find('#top-imageholder').html() );
      placeholder.append( $(data).find('#top-imageholder').siblings('ul') );
      return true;
    });
  });

})();
```