# Combine two json calls on one <ul> list

Tags: jquery, get, html-lists

I have the following code:

JSON call 1

```
$.get(url1, function(json){

  var list = '<ul>'

  $.each(json.data, function(index, value){
    list += '<li>'+value+'</li>'
  });

  list += '</ul>'

});
```

JSON call 2

```
$.get(url2, function(json){

  var list = '<ul>'

  $.each(json.data, function(index, value){
    list += '<li>'+value+'</li>'
  });

  list += '</ul>'

});
```

This code generates two separate unordered lists.

Can this be combined in a flexible way, so that I can merge the two lists, but not have nested JSON calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an use `$.when` to convert two promises into one:

```
$.when($.get(url1), $.get(url2)).done(function (res1, res2) {
  var list = '<ul>';

  var both = res1.data.concat(res2.data);
  $.each(both, function(index, value){
    list += '<li>'+value+'</li>';
  });

  list += '</ul>';

  // do something with list

})
```

`$.when` is useful to bring order to async ajax calls, while still keeping the efficiency of parallel requests.  Your other question:

[jQuery each with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480359/jquery-each-with-timeout/14482406#14482406)

can also be solved by using `$.when`.

Comment: This seems like a solution that I could use. However I'm only getting results from url1 in my list. Any idea why !??

Comment: Have you taken a look at res1 and res2 in debugger?

Comment: Yes, and they seem to be good. I get 2 objects containing arrays with different data.

Comment: I fixed a bug: `$.extend` only works with hashes, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to do that without nested AJAX calls. This should work:

```
var list = '<ul>';

function appendItems(json) {
    $.each(json.data, function(index, value) {
        list += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
    });
}

$.get(url1, function(json) {
    appendItems(json);
    $.get(url2, function(json) {
        appendItems(json);
        list += '</ul>';
        // list is complete
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
var list = '<ul>'
for(var i=1;i<=2;i++){    
     $.get('http://www.example.com/page'+i, function(json){

      $.each(json.data, function(index, value){
        list += '<li>'+value+'</li>'
      }); 

    });
}
list += '</ul>'
```

Comment: Remember that there are asynchronous calls, so `list += '</ul>'` may be called before AJAX handlers